SQL Server in Azure VM - cannot disable Telemetry event logs
We have several SQL Servers on VM in Azure - Server 2016 Standard with SQL 2017 Standard.
The system application logs are being spammed into oblivion by the Microsoft SQL VM Telemetry events with ID 51000 and 51001.
A excerpt of 5 events in a row:
[Information] TelemetryUtilityEvent: Successfully moved event file to event directory: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIaaSAgent\Events\133791954362302136.json
[Information] TelemetryUtilityEvent: Successfully wrote events to file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIaaSAgent\Events\Temp\133791954362302136.json
[Information] TelemetryEventLoggerEvent: Clearing out event queue for processing...
[Information] TelemetryUtilityEvent: Successfully created new event file: C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIaaSAgent\Events\Temp\133791954362302136.json
[Information] TelemetryEventLoggerEvent: Attempting to create a new event file...

I have disabled the data sharing via the SQL Server Error and Usage reporting and disabled + stopped the 3 CEIP related services for the SQL Server.
There are no Insights for SQL Server on VM. The VM Insights itself are not enabled. Nothing has been set as extra analytics for any of the DB servers.
Rebooted the VM, no difference.
What can i do to get rid of those? The events are created every second, if not several.

What do the events actually say? Do you have SQL Insights/database watcher/some other azure analytics that might generate those?. There are some extra telemetry options in SQL config manager > instance > advanced, which might help.

@Cpt.Whale Edited original post and added some log examples. The SQL Server Config Manager > SQL Server (instance) > Properties > Advanced lists 2 options that are probably related, but both are set to No - Customer Feedback Reporting, Error Reporting.

Looks like they are SQL IaaS extension logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-iaas-agent-extension-automate-management . I don't have a VM with this to test with, but there are some settings in the azure portal for it like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-agent-extension-troubleshoot-known-issues?view=azuresql#repair-extension . Maybe you can disable its telemetry there, or just disable the entire Microsoft SQL Server IaaS agent service if you don't want it
